# Calling COM method throws unexplainable COMException in C#, works fine in C++

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop

I'm learning about consuming a COM interface in C# by example, so I've written a coclass and interfaces for the `(I)DxDiagProvider` and `IDxDiagContainer` COM objects.

However, while the apparently equivalent code works fine in C++, calling one of it's methods fails with a `COMException` (HRESULT is -1) in C#. I probably messed something up porting it to C#, but can't see the error.

**Native code (working)**

The objects are defined in raw C as follows, which also is the only information I have on them (not having a library for tlbimp or anything):

```c
struct IDxDiagContainerVtbl;
struct IDxDiagContainer { IDxDiagContainerVtbl* lpVtbl; };
struct IDxDiagContainerVtbl
{
    HRESULT(__stdcall* QueryInterface)(IDxDiagContainer* This, const IID* const riid, void** ppvObject);
    ULONG(__stdcall* AddRef)(IDxDiagContainer* This);
    ULONG(__stdcall* Release)(IDxDiagContainer* This);
    HRESULT(__stdcall* EnumChildContainerNames)(IDxDiagContainer* This, DWORD dwIndex, LPWSTR pwszContainer, DWORD cchContainer);
    HRESULT(__stdcall* EnumPropNames)(IDxDiagContainer* This, DWORD dwIndex, LPWSTR pwszPropName, DWORD cchPropName);
    HRESULT(__stdcall* GetChildContainer)(IDxDiagContainer* This, LPCWSTR pwszContainer, IDxDiagContainer** ppInstance);
    HRESULT(__stdcall* GetNumberOfChildContainers)(IDxDiagContainer* This, DWORD* pdwCount);
    HRESULT(__stdcall* GetNumberOfProps)(IDxDiagContainer* This, DWORD* pdwCount);
    HRESULT(__stdcall* GetProp)(IDxDiagContainer* This, LPCWSTR pwszPropName, VARIANT* pvarProp);
};

struct DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS
{
    DWORD dwSize;
    DWORD dwDxDiagHeaderVersion;
    BOOL bAllowWHQLChecks;
    void* pReserved;
};
struct IDxDiagProviderVtbl;
struct IDxDiagProvider { IDxDiagProviderVtbl* lpVtbl; };
struct IDxDiagProviderVtbl
{
    HRESULT(__stdcall* QueryInterface)(IDxDiagProvider* This, const IID* const riid, void** ppvObject);
    ULONG(__stdcall* AddRef)(IDxDiagProvider* This);
    ULONG(__stdcall* Release)(IDxDiagProvider* This);
    HRESULT(__stdcall* Initialize)(IDxDiagProvider* This, DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS* pParams);
    HRESULT(__stdcall* GetRootContainer)(IDxDiagProvider* This, IDxDiagContainer** ppInstance);
};
```

Creating this and calling `Initialize` in native C++ works just fine:

```cpp
int main()
{
    GUID clsid;
    GUID iid;
    CLSIDFromString(L"{A65B8071-3BFE-4213-9A5B-491DA4461CA7}", &clsid);
    CLSIDFromString(L"{9C6B4CB0-23F8-49CC-A3ED-45A55000A6D2}", &iid);

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IDxDiagProvider* pDxDiagProvider;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, 1, iid, (LPVOID*)&pDxDiagProvider); // S_OK

    DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS params;
    params.dwSize = sizeof(DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS);
    params.dwDxDiagHeaderVersion = 111;
    params.bAllowWHQLChecks = 0;
    params.pReserved = 0;

    // Sorry for the C-like access, I don't have anything better than the structs above.
    hr = pDxDiagProvider->lpVtbl->Initialize(pDxDiagProvider, &params); // S_OK
}
```

**Managed code (broken)**

So then I went ahead and ported this to an `STAThread` x86 .NET 4.6.1 C# console program with the following definitions:

```cs
[ComImport]
[Guid("A65B8071-3BFE-4213-9A5B-491DA4461CA7")]
public class DxDiagProvider { }
[Guid("9C6B4CB0-23F8-49CC-A3ED-45A55000A6D2")]
public interface IDxDiagProvider
{
    void Initialize(ref DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS pParams);
    void GetRootContainer(ref IDxDiagContainer ppInstance);
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS
{
    public uint dwSize;
    public uint dwDxDiagHeaderVersion;
    public bool bAllowWHQLChecks;
    public IntPtr pReserved;
};

[Guid("7D0F462F-4064-4862-BC7F-933E5058C10F")]
public interface IDxDiagContainer
{
    void EnumChildContainerNames(uint dwIndex, string pwszContainer, uint cchContainer);
    void EnumPropNames(uint dwIndex, string pwszPropName, uint cchPropName);
    void GetChildContainer(string pwszContainer, ref IDxDiagContainer ppInstance);
    void GetNumberOfChildContainers(ref uint pdwCount);
    void GetNumberOfProps(ref uint pdwCount);
    void GetProp(string pwszPropName, ref IntPtr pvarProp);
}
```

Now, while creating the class and casting the interface works, the call to `Initialize` breaks with `COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFFF`:

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Working fine.
    DxDiagProvider dxDiagProviderClass = new DxDiagProvider();
    IDxDiagProvider dxDiagProvider = (IDxDiagProvider)dxDiagProviderClass;

    DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS initParams = new DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS
    {
        dwSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS>(),
        dwDxDiagHeaderVersion = 111
    };
    dxDiagProvider.Initialize(ref initParams); // causes COMException
}
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong. So far I've tested and checked the following things:

- Ensured the `DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS` struct is of correct size, alignment, layout
- Ensured my methods are in the right order and I did not add the `IUnknown` methods
- Tried adding `DispIdAttribute` to the interface methods, even though I think that's only relevant when hosting COM objects and not using them.
- Tried passing the parameters as non-ref, even though they should be `ref` as the parameter is a pointer.

I really hope this has nothing to do with the COM object not working correctly when used in a managed application (that would definitely make this question too broad). So I want to ensure my approach and my definitions are right at least. Is there anything else that has to be done and that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what I was missing and could fix it:

Apparently, I forgot to decorate the C# interfaces with the `InterfaceTypeAttribute` and specifying `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown`. At least for these COM objects, this is required, as the default `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual` causes the `COMException`s to be thrown.

E.g., the interface definitions now look like this in C# (plus I fixed some `ref` to `out` parameters, which however were not the cause of this issue):

```cs
[Guid("9C6B4CB0-23F8-49CC-A3ED-45A55000A6D2")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)] // <-- need this
public interface IDxDiagProvider
{
    void Initialize(ref DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS pParams);
    void GetRootContainer(out IDxDiagContainer ppInstance);
}

[Guid("7D0F462F-4064-4862-BC7F-933E5058C10F")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)] // <-- need this
public interface IDxDiagContainer
{
    void EnumChildContainerNames(uint dwIndex, string pwszContainer, uint cchContainer);
    void EnumPropNames(uint dwIndex, string pwszPropName, uint cchPropName);
    void GetChildContainer(string pwszContainer, out IDxDiagContainer ppInstance);
    void GetNumberOfChildContainers(out uint pdwCount);
    void GetNumberOfProps(out uint pdwCount);
    void GetProp(string pwszPropName, out IntPtr pvarProp);
}
```